# ERROR 404 IN PUBLIC DIRECTORY IN KOHANA CPANEL

Tags: http-status-code-404, kohana, cpanel, public

after having migrated from one VPS to a CPANEL, I have no access to public directory, because I get 404

What's the problem?

I have access to whm

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1
```

Inside the folder public I put this code in the .htaccess but nothing:

```
RewriteEngine off
```

Comment: vps = virtual private server. cpanel = tool for managing servers. You're basically saying "after migrating from a ferrari to a cheesebuger, nothing works".

Answer (score 0):

If you have root access of your server then login it through SSH and check your apache server error logs file. May be your account document root is incorrect OR you do not have any files on that path so please check your error logs so that you can easily find out root cause of this issues